# Data grid view showing columns but no data

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, datagridview

I can see the columns but not the data, maybe something to do with my code creating a new dataset, but I have no idea, here is my code:

```
  Private Sub frmClientDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DGVClient.Columns.Clear()
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection

    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client_Details"
    objdataadapter.Fill(New DataSet)

    DGVClient.ColumnCount = 9
    Call bind_dataset_DGVClient()
    Call count_records()
    rowposition = 0

    DGVClient.DataSource = objdataset
    DGVClient.DataMember = "Client_Details"
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSource` should be set to a `DataTable` not a `DataSet`.

```
Private Sub frmClientDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 Dim ds As New DataSet
 objdataadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand()
 objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection
 objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client_Details"
 objdataadapter.Fill(ds, "Client_Details")
 bind_dataset_DGVClient()
 count_records()
 rowposition = 0

 DGVClient.DataSource = ds.Tables("Client_Details")
```

End Sub

Comment: GREAT, finally something that worked! Only issue is, I have one set od all columns without any data then a repeat of all my columns with the data from my database.

Comment: Are you using `AutoGenerateColumns = True`

Comment: What does `bind_dataset_DGVClient()` do?

Comment: my code is:  
`Procedures used to bind the relevant data to the data grid, with the correct header titles.
    Public Sub bind_dataset_DGVClient()
        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.DataSource = objdataset
        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.DataMember = "client details"


        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Company Name"
        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Company Type"
        frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(2).HeaderText = "VAT Registration Number"
end sub
end module`

Comment: I will, what should I do about it?

Comment: The extra columns? Should I set autogenerate to false? Excuse me, I'm very new to this, just following tutorials.

Comment: If you set it to `False` then you have to manually set each column. Are you only wanting a couple of columns from this table and not the whole thing?

Comment: I would like all of them

Comment: You must have made some columns - maybe in the designer? Delete them if you did.

Comment: I did not, but I fixed it by deleting this code:       `DGVClient.ColumnCount = 9
        Call bind_dataset_DGVClient()` was this a mistake?

Comment: If it fixes your problem then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

objdataadapter.Fill(New DataSet) isn't returning anything that you have a reference to.  Try this

```
objdataset = New DataSet
objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset)
```

If you set a breakpoint right after that you can hover over objdataset and click on the Hour glass icon to see what is in the DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

I would put everything in an initialise sub and call it before showing the frame, so that the frame shows up when data is ready to be shown. I am not sure and I could not find a fast answer if MySqlDataAdapter's fill() method returns the number of records filled. This would make counting the rows easier.

```
     Private Sub initialise()
        DGVClient.Columns.Clear() 
        Dim sqlCmd As New MySqlCommand()
        sqlCmd.Connection = objconnection
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client_Details"
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset)
        rowposition = 0
        DGVClient.DataSource = objdataset.Table(0)
     End Sub

     Private Sub frmClientDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs)  Handles MyBase.Load

     End Sub
```